# JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance out of START_ARRAY token;

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of my.app.entities.Order out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of my.app.entities.Order out of START_ARRAY token
```

Store.java - file with controller

```
@Controller
public class Store {

 private OrderRepository               orderRepository;

 public Store(final OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

 @PostMapping("/order")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> getOrderInfo(@RequestBody final Order order) {

        this.orderRepository.save(order);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

OrderRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {

}
```

Order.java

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order extends Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer        id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOrder", nullable = true)
    private List<Products> orders;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(final List<Products> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
   //getters and setters
```

Products.java

```
@Entity
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int    price;

    public Products() {
    }

    public Products(final String name, final String description, final int price, final String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.id = id;

    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

So i'm trying to save a list of products in the repository but can't figure out how correct to deserialize this order object.

Edit 1:
I just added here JSON and it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Cherry",
        "description": "This is very good cherry",
        "price": 500
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Cucumber",
        "description": "This is an amazing cucumber",
        "price": 1000
    }
]
```

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Comment: add JSON object you are sending to post call

Comment: Based on your code, it appears you receive a service call containing an order in the payload.  if that is correct, do you have an automated test showing how you are calling the service?

Comment: Can you try adding @JsonProperty("<Property Name>")  to all variable?

Comment: jsut added JSON

Comment: Your JSON contains an array of `Products` [sic], while your endpoint only accepts a single `Order`, as such, your request payload is expected to contain an **object**, not an **array**.

Comment: Only change to this:
`@PostMapping("/order")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> saveOrders(@RequestBody List<Order> orders) {
        this.orderRepository.save(orders);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}`

Comment: @IbrahimAlTamimi I assume you meant `List<Products>`, because the objects in the json array match the `Products` class shown in the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Oh I'm sorry, you are right.

Comment: But this will change my response in save method to create a new order to hold all products.

Comment: thanks! and the main problem now how i can save my order to this.orderRepository?